# Visualize columns by top n results on Grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have below 2 dataframes, First dataframe `df1` tells how many records are there for each month in second `df2`.
(JFYI, `df1` is calculated from `df2` itself and grouped it by month to maintain the counts)

```
mainid  counts          month  
    1   13              JAN   
    2   15              JAN
    3   10              JAN 
    2   10              FEB
    3   5               FEB
    1   12              MAR
```

second df

```
mainid  stamp A                Value       month 
1       '2012-01-08 18:15:05'  'Value 01'   JAN
1       '2012-03-08 19:15:05'  'Value 02'   MAR
#... 25 (13+12 records for mainid 1 for JAN and MAR months of 2012)
2       '2012-01-08 18:15:05'  'Value 01'    JAN
2       '2012-02-08 19:15:05'  'Value 04'    FEB
#... 25 (15+10 records for mainid 2 for JAN and FEB months of 2012)
3       '2012-01-08 19:15:05'  'Value 06'    JAN
3       '2012-02-08 12:15:05'  'Value 06'    FEB
#... 15 (10+5 records for mainid 3 for JAN and FEB months of 2012)
```

Now, from `df2`, I want to show top 3 stamps and top 3 `values` in the `df1`.
I can calculate top3 like this, (but this would not be feasible for each `mainid`)

```
top3_stamps = df[df['mainid' == 1]].sort_values(['month','stamp A']).head(3)
top3_values = df[df['mainid' == 1]].sort_values(['month', 'Value']).head(3)
```

I am not getting, how can I find those top3 results for each `mainid` and combine it with `df1`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
top3_stamps = df.sort_values('stamp A').groupby('mainid').head(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, and sorry! my question needs a little edit, it need to be sorted by month as well. I will edit it. Also, How can I merge those top3  in df1? Where I want to see top3 `mainid`  records for each month?

Comment: @Laxmikant - Sorry, I was away. Still not 100% sure, because problem test with df2, is possible edit data e.g. for 2 groups with expected output after merge? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)